# Thrust zip_iterator - is typedef essential?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I tried to do this:

```
thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> zip;
zip = make_zip_iterator(...)
```

That failed to compile, but when I did this:

```
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTupe> ZipIterator;
ZipIterator zip = make_zip_iterator(...)
```

, my code compiled and did exactly what I wanted. My question is, why was the `typedef` required in this case? And is this usage of `typedef` specific to this context? I can post the rest of my code if somebody thinks the problem might have been elsewhere.

Comment: Typedef is not the only difference in your examples. What if you don't use typedef, but still initialize `zip` instead of assigning it later? As in `thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> zip = make_zip_iterator(...)`?

Comment: Anton, that works. I'm guessing that with `thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> zip`, there is an ambiguity of declaration and instantiation? How is this resolved?

Comment: There's no ambiguity, but maybe `zip_iterator` has no default constructor? It would explain the problem. I have no experience with the library you're using, but does a `zip_iterator` pointing *nowhere* make any sense, semantically? If it doesn't, there's no wonder that they don't provide default constructor for it. Then you should always initialize zip_iterators instead of assigning them later.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this:

```
thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> zip;
zip = make_zip_iterator(...)
```

fails is because the `thrust::zip_iterator` has no default constructor. This is a sensible design choice because an uninitialised fancy iterator has no practical use. The version including the `typedef` works because the copy constructor is used during instantiation of the fancy iterator. It is not a property of the `typedef` itself.

[This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered queue].